# PHP: Check if string is part of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on my little ticketing-system based on PHP.

Now I would like to exclude senders from being processed.

This is a possible list of excluded senders:

```
Array ( 
"badboy@example.com",
"example.org",
"spam@spamming.org"
)
```

Okay - now I would like to check if the sender of an mail matches one of these:

```
$sender = "badboy@example.com";
```

I think this is quite easy, I think I could solve this with `in_array()`.

But what about

```
$sender = "me@example.org";
```

`example.org` is defined in the array, but not `me@example.org` - but `me@example.org` should also excluded, because `example.org` is in the forbidden-senders-list.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) function.

```
<?php

if (!disallowedEmail($sender)) { // Check if email is disallowed
    // Do your stuff
}

function disallowedEmail($email) {
    $disallowedEmails = array ( 
        "badboy@example.com",
         "example.org",
         "spam@spamming.org"
     )
     foreach($disallowedEmails as $disallowed){
         if ( stripos($email, $disallowed) !== false)
             return true;
     }
     return false
}
```

Comment: i would use `stripos`

Answer (score 0):

Another short alternative with `stripos`, `implode` and `explode` functions:

```
$excluded = array( 
"badboy@example.com",
"example.org",
"spam@spamming.org"
);

$str = implode(",", $excluded);  // compounding string with excluded emails
$sender = "www@example.com";
//$sender = "me@example.org";

$domainPart = explode("@",$sender)[1];  // extracting domain part from a sender email

$isAllowed = stripos($str, $sender) === false && stripos($str, $domainPart) === false;

var_dump($isAllowed);    // output: bool(false)
```